# const Eigen::Affine3d; rotation()

Tags: moveit, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I have solved the forward kinematics with moveit.

```
kinemtic_state->setJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, joint_values);
const Eigen::Affine3d &arm_link_5_state = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("arm_link_5");

x = arm_link_5_state.translation().x();
y = arm_link_5_state.translation().y();
z = arm_link_5_state.translation().z();

xx = arm_link_5_state.rotation().??;
xy = arm_link_5_state.rotation().??;
xz = arm_link_5_state.rotation().??;
```

I don't know how to assign the value of xx, xy, xz of the rotation matrix.

I tried:

```
   xx = arm_link_5_state.rotation().xx();
   xx = arm_link_5_state.rotation().x().x();
   xx = arm_link_5_state.rotation().nx();
   xx = arm_link_5_state.rotation(0,0);
```

Error: const LinearMatrixType has no member named xx

I don't find the class where it is declared.

It would be great if someone can help me out.

Best regards,
Jonas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294125/const-eigen::affine3d;-rotation()/) by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-06-14**:
The accessor for the linear part of the affine transform is .linear(), not .rotation(). See docs [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html).

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-14**:
.linear().xx()? I don't find it in the doc.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-06-14**:
Check out this [tutorial](https://github.com/felipepolido/EigenExamples) and if you still can't figure it out update your question.

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-14**:
In my code I print the rotation with

ROS_INFO_STREAM("Rotation: " << arm_link_5_state.rotation());

and that works well.

I want to extract the individual values of the rotation matrix.

Thanks for your help @stevejp

**Comment by [JonasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/34613/jonasg/) on 2018-06-14**:
Now it works.

Thanks for that @stevejp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah I misspoke earlier, .rotation() is fine for pulling out the rotation matrix. To access individual elements you can do `Eigen::Matrix3d rot = arm_link_5_state.rotation()`, and then `xx = rot(0,0)`, etc.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1